# C# - Is it possible to extend an existing built-in class with a new Interface

Tags: c#, interface, reference, constants

I am just learning C# and I have a problem now. :-)
In C++ I loved to use "const reference" as a parameter to avoid that
the called method changes my passed object.

I read somewhere that I can do sth. similar in C# by using Interfaces.
In the interface I would just put some "getters" to allow the method a readonly access
to my object.

Now guess, that I want to pass my C# method a built-in container like "List".
But I want to avoid that the method changes something in that list.
Just read only!

My first thought was:
- I create a new Interface called IMyOwnInterface, which uses the interface IList as well

- My new interface IMyOwnInterface contains only "getters"
- I change my method to sth. like that  MyLittleMethod(IMyOwnInterface if)
- Now the method "MyLittleMethod" can just see the "getters", which I put in my own interface and not the "setters" of IList

Is this possible?
Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use List.AsReadOnly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(VS.80).aspx

Comment: IList has no AsReadOnly method.

Comment: @Miriam: If it's an IList<T> in C# 3, you can use list.ToList().AsReadOnly().

Comment: You can always do a `IList<T> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(mutableList);` which creates an access wrapper for the original list (changes to the original list will be reflected in the readonly list).

Comment: @Lucero ReadOnlyCollection works just for List but what if I want to use a Dictionary?

Comment: @mrbamboo: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ReadOnlyDictionary.aspx.  Easily found on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that would work. Give it a shot, and let us know how it works :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no:

IList does not implement IMyOwnInterface so you can't cast it.

```
IList list = ...
MyLittleMethod((IMyOwnInterface)list)    // Compiler errror here
```

In this case you can use ReadOnlycollection:

```
IList list = ...
MyLittleMethod(new ReadOnlyCollection(list))
```

Comment: I use now ReadOnlyCollection for the case of List but Dictionaries?
There is no ReadOnly... for Dictionaries, right?

Answer (score 0):

With interfaces, it's basically only possible through inheritance or with some proxy stuff (either explicit with an adapter class, via a RealProxy implementation, or with a library to do things like that, such as LinFu).

However, out of the box you can use delegates to do late-binding for single methods with matching signature.

Comment: Very complicated, especially for a beginner.